# For loop over a grouped tibble: to run gam LOESS with specific span value for each group

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to run several (85), independent GAM LOESS models simultaneously over a grouped tibble. For the example here, only 2 models. I have a list of span values (`span`; it's a vector) for each model (or group in the tibble) which I would like to use in the for loop so every time it runs a model it will use the appropriate span value from the `span` list.

The data:

```
> print(turning_rate_4954, n=100)
# A tibble: 100 x 6
# Groups:   TEMP, REP, VIDEO, SHARK [2]
    TEMP  REP   VIDEO SHARK turn_rate_dgs_s  Time_s
    <fct> <fct> <fct> <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>
  1 29    1     1      4954             0   0      
  2 29    1     1      4954          -244.  0.00416
  3 29    1     1      4954           947.  0.00832
  4 29    1     1      4954           790.  0.0125 
  5 29    1     1      4954          1534.  0.0166 
  6 29    1     1      4954           791.  0.0208 
  7 29    1     1      4954          1811.  0.0250 
  8 29    1     1      4954          1392.  0.0291 
  9 29    1     1      4954          1170.  0.0333 
 10 29    1     1      4954          1676.  0.0374 
 11 29    1     1      4954          1360.  0.0416 
 12 29    1     1      4954          1571.  0.0458 
 13 29    1     1      4954          1344.  0.0499 
 14 29    1     1      4954           984.  0.0541 
 15 29    1     1      4954           925.  0.0582 
 16 29    1     1      4954           600.  0.0624 
 17 29    1     1      4954           506.  0.0666 
 18 29    1     1      4954             0   0.0707 
 19 29    1     1      4954          -135.  0.0749 
 20 29    1     1      4954           -92.3 0.0790 
 21 29    1     1      4954          -441.  0.0832 
 22 29    1     1      4954          -926.  0.0874 
 23 29    1     1      4954          -403.  0.0915 
 24 29    1     1      4954          -385.  0.0957 
 25 29    1     1      4954          -863.  0.0998 
 26 29    1     1      4954          -531.  0.104  
 27 29    1     1      4954          -357.  0.108  
 28 29    1     1      4954          -744.  0.112  
 29 29    1     1      4954         -1785.  0.116  
 30 29    1     1      4954         -1132.  0.121  
 31 29    1     1      4954          -693.  0.125  
 32 29    1     1      4954          -916.  0.129  
 33 29    1     1      4954         -1132.  0.133  
 34 29    1     1      4954         -1802.  0.137  
 35 29    1     1      4954         -1043.  0.141  
 36 29    1     1      4954         -1017.  0.146  
 37 29    1     1      4954          -763.  0.150  
 38 29    1     1      4954         -1009.  0.154  
 39 29    1     1      4954          -540.  0.158  
 40 29    1     1      4954          -450.  0.162  
 41 29    1     1      4954          -725.  0.166  
 42 29    1     1      4954          -473.  0.171  
 43 29    1     1      4954          -463.  0.175  
 44 29    1     1      4954          -453.  0.179  
 45 29    1     1      4954          -533.  0.183  
 46 29    1     1      4954          -752.  0.187  
 47 29    1     1      4954          -109.  0.191  
 48 29    1     1      4954             0   0.196  
 49 29    1     1      4954           211.  0.200  
 50 29    1     1      4954             0   0.204  
 51 29    1     2      4954             0   0      
 52 29    1     2      4954           115.  0.00416
 53 29    1     2      4954           559.  0.00832
 54 29    1     2      4954           935.  0.0125 
 55 29    1     2      4954           986.  0.0166 
 56 29    1     2      4954          1606.  0.0208 
 57 29    1     2      4954          1578.  0.0250 
 58 29    1     2      4954          2195.  0.0291 
 59 29    1     2      4954          1178.  0.0333 
 60 29    1     2      4954          1699.  0.0374 
 61 29    1     2      4954          1875.  0.0416 
 62 29    1     2      4954          1648.  0.0458 
 63 29    1     2      4954          1597.  0.0499 
 64 29    1     2      4954          2239.  0.0541 
 65 29    1     2      4954          2221.  0.0582 
 66 29    1     2      4954          2278.  0.0624 
 67 29    1     2      4954          1783.  0.0666 
 68 29    1     2      4954          1678.  0.0707 
 69 29    1     2      4954          1747.  0.0749 
 70 29    1     2      4954          1479.  0.0790 
 71 29    1     2      4954          2035.  0.0832 
 72 29    1     2      4954          2378.  0.0874 
 73 29    1     2      4954          1826.  0.0915 
 74 29    1     2      4954          1659.  0.0957 
 75 29    1     2      4954          2344.  0.0998 
 76 29    1     2      4954          1839.  0.104  
 77 29    1     2      4954          1044.  0.108  
 78 29    1     2      4954          1789.  0.112  
 79 29    1     2      4954           721.  0.116  
 80 29    1     2      4954           946.  0.121  
 81 29    1     2      4954           143.  0.125  
 82 29    1     2      4954           376.  0.129  
 83 29    1     2      4954             0   0.133  
 84 29    1     2      4954          -418.  0.137  
 85 29    1     2      4954           127.  0.141  
 86 29    1     2      4954         -1053.  0.146  
 87 29    1     2      4954          -535.  0.150  
 88 29    1     2      4954            87.4 0.154  
 89 29    1     2      4954          -437.  0.158  
 90 29    1     2      4954          -730.  0.162  
 91 29    1     2      4954          -441.  0.166  
 92 29    1     2      4954          -553.  0.171  
 93 29    1     2      4954          -893.  0.175  
 94 29    1     2      4954          -694.  0.179  
 95 29    1     2      4954          -847.  0.183  
 96 29    1     2      4954           313.  0.187  
 97 29    1     2      4954           581.  0.191  
 98 29    1     2      4954          1121.  0.196  
 99 29    1     2      4954          1753.  0.200  
100 29    1     2      4954          1504.  0.204  
>
```

I created a function that contains the GAM LOESS function. I did this because the GAM formula won't accept indexing (*i.e.*, can't use `span[[i]]` inside the formula):

```
##Creat custom function to do a GAM LOESS-------------------------
mygamLoess <- function(x, y, data, degree=1, span=span){
    library(gam)
    gam::gam(y ~ lo(x, span= span, degree= degree), data= data)
}
```

After this, I did the for loop and use the `mygamLoess` function inside. Here is where the problem happens. The idea is to do the GAMs over a grouped tibble, therefore I run `mygamLoess` inside a pipe. It does the models but using only the fist value of span in `span`.

```
##Loop to create single models, each with its unique span value-----------

span <- c(0.5, 0.3) # the span values to use for each model respectively

list_mymodels = list() #prepare an empty list to store the models
for(i in 1:2){
    span1 <- span[[i]] #this should get the span value
    list_mymodels <- turning_rate_4954 %>% 
                     group_by(TEMP, SHARK, VIDEO) %>% 
    do(models= mygamLoess(x=.$Time_s, 
                          y=.$turn_rate_dgs_s, 
                          data=., 
                          span= span1, 
                          degree=1)             )

}

#Inspect results
head(list_mymodels$models) #models list


list_mymodels$models[[2]]$model$lo["span"] #the span used in model 2
```

This works pretty well and run a single model for each group in the tibble. The problem is that is using always the first value of span in `span`. So the second model will have `span=0.5` instead of `span=0.3`. Looks like the indexing of `span` is not working inside the pipe(?)

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use index to store the models. In your current code, you are overwriting the models in  `list_mymodels`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

span <- c(0.5, 0.3)
list_mymodels = vector('list', length(span)) 
for(i in seq_along(list_mymodels)) {
  span1 <- span[[i]] 
  list_mymodels[[i]] <- turning_rate_4954 %>% 
                           group_by(TEMP, SHARK, VIDEO) %>% 
                           do(models= mygamLoess(x=.$Time_s, 
                                                 y=.$turn_rate_dgs_s, 
                                                 data=., 
                                                 span= span1, 
                                                 degree=1))

}
```

Instead of `for` loop, you can use `map` or `lapply` :

```
list_mymodels <- map(span, ~turning_rate_4954 %>% 
                    group_by(TEMP, SHARK, VIDEO) %>% 
                    do(models= mygamLoess(x=.$Time_s, 
                                          y=.$turn_rate_dgs_s, 
                                          data=., 
                                          span= .x, 
                                          degree=1)))
```

---

If we want to apply only one model in each group we can use `map2`.

```
list_mymodels <- turning_rate_4954 %>%
                     group_split(TEMP, SHARK, VIDEO) %>%
                     map2(span, ~mygamLoess(x=.x$Time_s, 
                                            y=.x$turn_rate_dgs_s, 
                                            data=.x, 
                                            span= .y, 
                                            degree=1))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for your answer. It looks pretty close, but it's doing way too much more models than I want. So basically what it is doing now is running 2 models for each group. The first time using `span=0.5` (for both groups), and the second time using `span=0.3`. Resulting in a list of 2 tibbles with 2 models each (total 4 models, instead of 2). In my case, as I have 85 models, it would mean 7,225 models. It makes impossible to find the right one (_i.e._, the one with its appropriate span value). Even with 2 models as I would have to manually find the right one.

Comment: @JoseE.Trujillo So you want to apply `span = 0.5` for first group and `span = 0.3` for 2nd group. So in this example, only 2 models? See the edit in last part of the answer.

Comment: Yes, `span=0.5` for first group and `span=0.3` for the second. Fantastic!! `map2` worked perfect. Thanks Ronak!!